# Problems up setting up codeigniter with sparks & active record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-2, phpactiverecord

I am having problems getting my `sparks` install to work with my `codeigniter` install

here are the steps I took which were as follows:

1. I went to my root of my `codeigniter` project folder through my `PHPCLI` to install sparks using the below command

   ```
   php -r "$(curl -fsSL http://getsparks.org/go-sparks)"
   ```
2. i installed the active record library using the spark command below

   ```
   php tools\spark install -v0.0.2 php-activerecord
   ```

2a. this command gave me the follwing folder structure

```
-application
-sparks
   -php-activerecord
      -0.0.2
         -config
         -variables
         -vendor
-system
-tests
-tools
   -lib
      -spark
         -sparktypes
   -test
-user_guide
```

2b. this command generates a `sparks` containing `php active record` folder that makeup the necessary components of `php-activerecord`, the command using generates a `MY_Loader.php` file which looks like this

```
<?php  if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/**
 * Sparks
 *
 * An open source application development framework for PHP 5.1.6 or newer
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @author      CodeIgniter Reactor Dev Team
 * @author      Kenny Katzgrau <katzgrau@gmail.com>
 * @since       CodeIgniter Version 1.0
 * @filesource
 */

/**
 * Loader Class
 *
 * Loads views and files
 *
 * @package     CodeIgniter
 * @subpackage  Libraries
 * @author      CodeIgniter Reactor Dev Team
 * @author      Kenny Katzgrau <katzgrau@gmail.com>
 * @category    Loader
 * @link        http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/loader.html
 */
class MY_Loader extends CI_Loader
{
    /**
     * Keep track of which sparks are loaded. This will come in handy for being
     *  speedy about loading files later.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    var $_ci_loaded_sparks = array();

    /**
     * Is this version less than CI 2.1.0? If so, accomodate
     * @bubbafoley's world-destroying change at: http://bit.ly/sIqR7H
     * @var bool
     */
    var $_is_lt_210 = false;

    /**
     * Constructor. Define SPARKPATH if it doesn't exist, initialize parent
     */
    function __construct()
    {
        if(!defined('SPARKPATH'))
        {
            define('SPARKPATH', 'sparks/');
        }

        $this->_is_lt_210 = (is_callable(array('CI_Loader', 'ci_autoloader'))
                               || is_callable(array('CI_Loader', '_ci_autoloader')));

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * To accomodate CI 2.1.0, we override the initialize() method instead of
     *  the ci_autoloader() method. Once sparks is integrated into CI, we
     *  can avoid the awkward version-specific logic.
     * @return Loader
     */
    function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        if(!$this->_is_lt_210)
        {
            $this->ci_autoloader();
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Load a spark by it's path within the sparks directory defined by
     *  SPARKPATH, such as 'markdown/1.0'
     * @param string $spark The spark path withint he sparks directory
     * @param <type> $autoload An optional array of items to autoload
     *  in the format of:
     *   array (
     *     'helper' => array('somehelper')
     *   )
     * @return <type>
     */
    function spark($spark, $autoload = array())
    {
        if(is_array($spark))
        {
            foreach($spark as $s)
            {
                $this->spark($s);
            }
        }

        $spark = ltrim($spark, '/');
        $spark = rtrim($spark, '/');

        $spark_path = SPARKPATH . $spark . '/';
        $parts      = explode('/', $spark);
        $spark_slug = strtolower($parts[0]);

        # If we've already loaded this spark, bail
        if(array_key_exists($spark_slug, $this->_ci_loaded_sparks))
        {
            return true;
        }

        # Check that it exists. CI Doesn't check package existence by itself
        if(!file_exists($spark_path))
        {
            show_error("Cannot find spark path at $spark_path");
        }

        if(count($parts) == 2)
        {
            $this->_ci_loaded_sparks[$spark_slug] = $spark;
        }

        $this->add_package_path($spark_path);

        foreach($autoload as $type => $read)
        {
            if($type == 'library')
                $this->library($read);
            elseif($type == 'model')
                $this->model($read);
            elseif($type == 'config')
                $this->config($read);
            elseif($type == 'helper')
                $this->helper($read);
            elseif($type == 'view')
                $this->view($read);
            else
                show_error ("Could not autoload object of type '$type' ($read) for spark $spark");
        }

        // Looks for a spark's specific autoloader
        $this->ci_autoloader($spark_path);

        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Pre-CI 2.0.3 method for backward compatility.
     *
     * @param null $basepath
     * @return void
     */
    function _ci_autoloader($basepath = NULL)
    {
        $this->ci_autoloader($basepath);
    }

    /**
     * Specific Autoloader (99% ripped from the parent)
     *
     * The config/autoload.php file contains an array that permits sub-systems,
     * libraries, and helpers to be loaded automatically.
     *
     * @param array|null $basepath
     * @return void
     */
    function ci_autoloader($basepath = NULL)
    {
        if($basepath !== NULL)
        {
            $autoload_path = $basepath.'config/autoload'.EXT;
        }
        else
        {
            $autoload_path = APPPATH.'config/autoload'.EXT;
        }

        if(! file_exists($autoload_path))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        include($autoload_path);

        if ( ! isset($autoload))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }

        if($this->_is_lt_210 || $basepath !== NULL)
        {
            // Autoload packages
            if (isset($autoload['packages']))
            {
                foreach ($autoload['packages'] as $package_path)
                {
                    $this->add_package_path($package_path);
                }
            }
        }

        // Autoload sparks
        if (isset($autoload['sparks']))
        {
            foreach ($autoload['sparks'] as $spark)
            {
                $this->spark($spark);
            }
        }

        if($this->_is_lt_210 || $basepath !== NULL)
        {
            if (isset($autoload['config']))
            {
                // Load any custom config file
                if (count($autoload['config']) > 0)
                {
                    $CI =& get_instance();
                    foreach ($autoload['config'] as $key => $val)
                    {
                        $CI->config->load($val);
                    }
                }
            }

            // Autoload helpers and languages
            foreach (array('helper', 'language') as $type)
            {
                if (isset($autoload[$type]) AND count($autoload[$type]) > 0)
                {
                    $this->$type($autoload[$type]);
                }
            }

            // A little tweak to remain backward compatible
            // The $autoload['core'] item was deprecated
            if ( ! isset($autoload['libraries']) AND isset($autoload['core']))
            {
                $autoload['libraries'] = $autoload['core'];
            }

            // Load libraries
            if (isset($autoload['libraries']) AND count($autoload['libraries']) > 0)
            {
                // Load the database driver.
                if (in_array('database', $autoload['libraries']))
                {
                    $this->database();
                    $autoload['libraries'] = array_diff($autoload['libraries'], array('database'));
                }

                // Load all other libraries
                foreach ($autoload['libraries'] as $item)
                {
                    $this->library($item);
                }
            }

            // Autoload models
            if (isset($autoload['model']))
            {
                $this->model($autoload['model']);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

1. i modify my `autoload.php` to include php active record as below

   ```
   $autoload['sparks'] = array('php-activerecord/0.0.2');
   ```

when i run my codeigniter site i get the following error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Use of undefined constant EXT - assumed 'EXT'

Filename: core/MY_Loader.php

Line Number: 174

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\application\core\MY_Loader.php
Line: 174
Function: _exception_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\application\core\MY_Loader.php
Line: 154
Function: ci_autoloader

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\application\core\MY_Loader.php
Line: 67
Function: initialize

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\index.php
Line: 274
Function: require_once
```

I am curious as to what could be causing this error? Please let me know if there is any other configuration that I am missing or if theres a mistake that I have made.

Comment: i replaced $autoload_path = $basepath.'config/autoload'.EXT;

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `EXT` is defined in your root `index.php` file.

```
// The PHP file extension
// this global constant is deprecated.
define('EXT', '.php');
```

See if it's still there or not?

Comment: the errors went away thanks but i still have a problem getting orm to work

Comment: You're right but I'd add this definition in the application/config/constants.php file.

Answer (score 1):

IN case that constant is not there, you can also define the autoload.php without using the constant.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but hopefully this will save someone some time... I had the same issue and the above fix did not work. I finally fixed the issue in the htaccess file by removing the RewriteBase although I am not sure why this caused the issue in the first place.

just commented out the line as follows:

```
RewriteBase /
```

to

```
#RewriteBase /
```