# ActiveRecord\MysqliAdapter not found

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, phpactiverecord

I am trying to implement PHPActiveRecord based on the previous problem I had in the previous Stack Overflow post
[setting up sparks with php-activerecord in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006456/problems-up-setting-up-codeigniter-with-sparks-active-record)

I put that code in the constructor and my error vanished (phew).

But now on to testing that orm works. I created model called User.php in the models folder with the following code

```
<?php

class User extends ActiveRecord\Model {


}  

?>
```

Then I went on to create a table in my database for testing wit php-activerecord to see if orm works.
So I decided to have database called "spark" with a table called "users" using the following SQL code below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

--
-- Dumping data for table `users`
--

INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `username`, `password`) VALUES
(1, 'shawn', ''),
(2, 'justin', '');
```

Also my database.php is configured to match the table as follows:

```
$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'spark',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => TRUE,
    'db_debug' => TRUE,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'autoinit' => TRUE,
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array()
);
```

Dats the database sorted, so I opened the welcome.php controller and add the following code into the index method as below

```
public function index()
    {
        

        $users = User::all();

        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($users);
    }
```

i ran it in the browser and I got the following errors as below

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException' with message 'ActiveRecord\MysqliAdapter not found!' in C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-
activerecord\lib\Connection.php:127 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php(98):
ActiveRecord\Connection::load_adapter_class('mysqli') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\ConnectionManager.php(33):
ActiveRecord\Connection::instance('mysqli://root:@...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Table.php(103):
ActiveRecord\ConnectionManager::get_connection(NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Table.php(80):
ActiveRecord\Table->reestablish_connection(false) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Table.php(61):
ActiveRecord\Table->__construct('User') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\ve in C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php on line 127


A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Error

Message: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException' with message 'ActiveRecord\MysqliAdapter not found!' in C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-
activerecord\lib\Connection.php:127 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Connection.php(98):
ActiveRecord\Connection::load_adapter_class('mysqli') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\ConnectionManager.php(33):
ActiveRecord\Connection::instance('mysqli://root:@...') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Table.php(103):
ActiveRecord\ConnectionManager::get_connection(NULL) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Table.php(80):
ActiveRecord\Table->reestablish_connection(false) #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-activerecord\lib\Table.php(61): 
ActiveRecord\Table->__construct('User') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\ve

Filename: lib/Connection.php

Line Number: 127

Backtrace:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is pretty clearly shown in the exception message:

Message: Uncaught exception 'ActiveRecord\DatabaseException' with message 'ActiveRecord\MysqliAdapter not found!' in C:\xampp\htdocs\orm\sparks\php-activerecord\0.0.2\vendor\php-

It's trying to load a mysqli adapter for the ActiveRecord library and not finding it. Either that library is not fully installed (missing optional mysqli module, perhaps) or the include path is not set up correctly to autoload its classes.

Comment: i just gonna be man and install active record through composer so that i can autoload it properly

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm facing the same issue while upgrading Codeigniter version

Answer (score 1):

[PHPActiveRecord](https://github.com/machuga/php-activerecord-spark) is built on top of PDO, not mysqli. This library doesn't have support for mysqli. The reason why you are seeing this error message is that you have specified `'dbdriver' => 'mysqli'` but PDO doesn't have a mysqli driver, nor does this library you are trying to use.

To fix the error simply specify `mysql` as the driver.

```
'dbdriver' => 'mysql'
```